# Getting AttributeError on nltk Textual entailment classifier

Tags: python, nltk, text-classification

Im referring to the link in the section
http://www.nltk.org/book/ch06.html#recognizing-textual-entailment

```
def rte_features(rtepair):
    extractor = nltk.RTEFeatureExtractor(rtepair)
    features = {}
    features['word_overlap'] = len(extractor.overlap('word'))
    features['word_hyp_extra'] = len(extractor.hyp_extra('word'))
    features['ne_overlap'] = len(extractor.overlap('ne'))
    features['ne_hyp_extra'] = len(extractor.hyp_extra('ne'))
    return features
rtepair = nltk.corpus.rte.pairs(['rte3_dev.xml'])

extractor = nltk.RTEFeatureExtractor(rtepair)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-a7f96e33ba9e> in <module>()
----> 1 extractor = nltk.RTEFeatureExtractor(rtepair)

C:\Users\RAVINA\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\nltk\classify\rte_classify.pyc in __init__(self, rtepair, stop, lemmatize)
     65 
     66         #Get the set of word types for text and hypothesis
---> 67         self.text_tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(rtepair.text)
     68         self.hyp_tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(rtepair.hyp)
     69         self.text_words = set(self.text_tokens)

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Its the exact code as mentioned in the book, can anyone help me whats going wrong here.
Thanks
Ravina

Comment: It's not the exact same code as mentioned in the book:
`rtepair = nltk.corpus.rte.pairs(['rte3_dev.xml'])[33]`
They take the 33rd element of the list, not the whole list.

Comment: Im sorry but you are getting it wrong, [33] is just a legend, mentioning the 33rd code snippet. :-)

Comment: "To illustrate the content of these features, we examine some attributes of the text/hypothesis Pair 34 shown earlier:". They mean item number 34 (33 + 1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the type signatures. Type this into the python shell:

```
import nltk
x = nltk.corpus.rte.pairs(['rte3_dev.xml'])
type(x)
```

tells you `x` is of type list.

Now, type:

```
help(nltk.RTEFeatureExtractor)
```

which tells you:

> :param rtepair: a `RTEPair` from which features should be extracted

Clearly, `x` does not have the correct type for calling `nltk.RTEFeatureExtractor`. Instead:

```
type(x[33])
<class 'nltk.corpus.reader.rte.RTEPair'>
```

A single item of the list does have the correct type.

---

**Update:**
As mentioned in the comment section, `extractor.text_words` shows only empty strings. This seems to be due to changes made in NLTK since the documentation was written. Long story short: You won't be able to fix this without downgrading to an older version of NLTK or fixing the problem in NLTK yourself.
Inside the file `nltk/classify/rte_classify.py`, you will find the following piece of code:

```
class RTEFeatureExtractor(object):
    …
    import nltk
    from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
    tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer('([A-Z]\.)+|\w+|\$[\d\.]+')
    self.text_tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(rtepair.text)
    self.text_words = set(self.text_tokens)
```

If you run the same `RegexpTokenizer` with the exact text from the extractor, it will produce only empty strings:

```
import nltk
rtepair = nltk.corpus.rte.pairs(['rte3_dev.xml'])[33]
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer('([A-Z]\.)+|\w+|\$[\d\.]+')
tokenizer.tokenize(rtepair.text)
```

Returns `['', '', …, '']` (i.e., a list of empty strings).

Comment: What does it say when you type `type(nltk.corpus.rte.pairs(['rte3_dev.xml'])[33])` into the python shell?

Comment: The code works perfectly fine for me with nltk version 3.1. You're either doing something wrong or you have another version of nltk. Here's the code that worked for me: http://sprunge.us/KXNK

Comment: But  - print(extractor.text_words)   , doesnt give me any output.

Comment: See the update in my answer. The bug is either in the NLTK documentation, or the code of NLTK.